# Undocumented limit on Outlook calendar event entries return by Microsoft Graph

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I've been using graph explorer to experiment with bringing back events in my calendar. Details here:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendarview

I've noticed that I never seem to get back more than 10 entries, even when I specify a period when there are more than 10 entries in my calendar for that time period. The documentation doesn't seem to mention this limit so I wondered whether it was the intended behaviour or if it's a bug?

Steps to reproduce:

- go to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#
- click show more samples
- check outlook calendar
- make sure you have more than 10 entries in your outlook calendar
- check 'All events in my calendar for next week'
- only 10 objects are returned in the 'value' array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the API in question, however have you considered using the OData $top query parameter as discussed in the [paging](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/paging) section and detailed in the [query parameters specification](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters)?